# Single file components not rendering with Vuejs in Electron app

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, electron

I've been using the `electron-webpack` module to try to get a project running with `vuejs`. I started out with their [quick-start](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack-quick-start) repo to see if I could get it up and running.

I can see that my components are being loaded. They appear to being processed by babel. Vue even runs, and I can see the root component in the vue developer tool. But, when I try to use a single file component, in the ways I see other people using them, nothing renders.

### index.vue (main file)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { App }
})
```

### App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Main View</h1>
    <jester />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Jester from './jester.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: { jester: Jester },
    data () {
      return {
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

### jester.vue

```
<template>
  <p>This is the Jester component {{something}}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'jester',
  data () {
    return {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm having trouble discerning why this would load a blank page. I'm using the recommended [electron-webpack-vue](https://webpack.electron.build/add-ons#vuejs) which should load up `vue-loader` for webpack, and allow my components to be processed into javascript, and I believe that step is working, I checked to see if I could find translations of my modules in the `renderer.js` file included in the page source.

The complete code for the project is here: https://github.com/counterbeing/electron-webpack-quick-start

If you want to try running it you should be able to clone it, and just run `yarn; yarn dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the `template` property in your `renderer/index.js` file.

just add:

`new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})`

:)

Comment: Wow, you sorted that one quickly. I thought it was an issue with my vuejs usage. And it was. May I ask one more thing regarding this? I saw someone else do something like this instead, but it didn't work for me: `render: h => h(app)`, they defined that rather than a template, and i tried, but didn't have any luck with it. Is one preferable over the other? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, but personally, I never had used the render function before.

It looks like an alternative to specific cases of templates, when you want to switch between different items, but it has an specific syntax too.

I saw the official documentation link:

https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html